# Ruby on rails error: param is missing or the value is empty

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I can't seem to debug this error. I am following the Ruby on rails tutorial located here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html

The error is coming from my controller, here's the code for it:

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @articles = Article.all
  end

  def show
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
  end

  def create
    @article = Article.new(params.require(article_params))

    @article.save
    redirect_to @article
  end

  private
    def article_params
      params.require(:article).permit(:title, :text)
    end
end
```

The error is coming from this line specifically:

```
@article = Article.new(params.require(article_params))
```

Here's my view in case you need it:

```
<h1>New Article </h1>

<%= form_for :article, url: articles_path do |f| %>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :title %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= f.label :text %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :text %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= f.submit %>
  </p>

<% end %>
```

Comment: put this @article = Article.new article_params

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be

```
@article = Article.new(article_params)
```

As you have already permitted the attributes in `article_params` method

Comment: Wow, I'm an idiot. I can't believe i didn't see this.

Comment: I did find it helpful, I had to wait for the timer before I can accept.

Answer (score 0):

Please also note that you had written

```
@article = Article.new(params.require(article_params))
```

whereas it should be

```
@article = Article.new(params.require[article_params])
```

i.e. [] instead of () around article_params.